# MySQLi query order by as variable?

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQLi query:

```
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM `new_albums` WHERE `city_name` = '$city' AND `venue_name` LIKE '%$venue_name%' AND `amount_of_files` > '$img_count' AND (`album_date` >= '$date1' AND `album_date` <= '$date2') '$orderby' LIMIT $start_results, 12";
```

It doesn't function until I remove:

`'$orderby'`

The `$orderby` variable is selected by the user and is changeable so it needs to be a variable:

```
if($order_by == 'most_viewed'){
        $orderby = '`viewed_count` DESC';
    }
    if($order_by == 'least_viewed'){
        $orderby = '`viewed_count` ASC';
    }
    if($order_by == 'date_created_desc'){
        $orderby = '`date_added` DESC';
    }
    if($order_by == 'date_created_asc'){
        $orderby = '`date_added` ASC';
    }
    if($order_by == 'most_files'){
        $orderby = '`amount_of_files` DESC';
    }
    if($order_by == 'least_files'){
        $orderby = '`amount_of_files` ASC';
    }
```

Is there any way I can get this query to function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the MySQL keyword `ORDER BY`, e.g.

```
$orderby = 'ORDER BY `date_added` DESC';
```

Comment: thats one of those things, derp